# Как узнать установленную версию приложения на устройстве

Tags: android

Как проверить какая версия приложения (в моём случае youtube) установлена?

p.s. Если вообще не установлена, то как это узнать?

**UPDATE1** Не как пользователь, а как разработчик

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого есть специальные классы [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) и [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html):

```
try {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);
    TextView version = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.version);
    version.setText(packageInfo.versionName);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {}
```

Если нужна другая информация - смотрите по ссылке.

Если нужно для ютуба, то заменяем `this.getPackageName()` на `"com.google.android.youtube"`.

Конечно, если автор поленился и не прописал в манифесте версию, то задача сильно усложняется.

Comment: А как значение packageInfo превратить в нормальный вид (вроде 4.2.1)? packageInfo.toString возвращает непонятное "PacksgeInfo{4272ecb8 com.google.android.youtube}"?

Comment: Посмотрите в код - `packageInfo.versionName`

Comment: @danpetruk а что не суждено посмотреть на доку [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html)? `PackageInfo.toString()` - выдает хэш объекта...

P.S. Ну вы блин даете...

Comment: Еле-еле откопал в доке packageInfo.versionName

Comment: а в примере, котором я привел, нет этого:) пришлось в доках копаться...